# Document more than one repos with MkDocs

Tags: python, django, mkdocs

I got a special situation where I have a few Django packages that work closely together, and I want to document them together at one place.

- **medux-common**: common used models, views, etc.
- **medux**: main application
- **medux-online**: web interface for certain functions
- **medux-docs**: the documentation package

Both *medux-online* and *medux* use the *common* module, and I don't want to have 3 documentation homepages, but just one where all is documented at one place.

Is there a possibility in MkDocs to "load" external packages? I use the `mkdocstrings` plugin to load the docstrings from my code. Its docs says, that the path must be set so that the module to document must be importable.

In my `medux-docs` package, I import all the other packages using `pip install -e ../medux` etc., which works fine. But MkDocs does not find them:

```
$ mkdocs serve
[...]
ERROR    -  mkdocstrings: medux.core.middleware could not be found
ERROR    -  Could not collect 'medux.core.middleware'
```

How do I do that? I don't want to merge all repositories into one, as medux and medux-online should be 2 pypi packages too. I just want MkDocs to find the imported medux, medux-online, and medux-common.
Do I completely think the wrong way?

Comment: I have a similar question, though it's because I'm trying to build an internal documentation site. I've asked it [on superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1827866/231154), but I might create it here since I don't have to make new tags.

Answer (score 0):

Recent mkdocstrings versions should support this use-case. By default, the underlying library responsible for finding sources and extracting info, Griffe, will look into `PYTHONPATH` / `sys.path` for specified packages (for example `medux`, `medux_common`, etc.).

If it can't find some packages, it means that they are not installed, or that their editable installation method (`pip install -e`) is not supported (there are many different methods for editable installs). In that case, feel free to open a feature request on [Griffe's tracker](https://github.com/mkdocstrings/griffe/issues), including necessary information like your build backend, the contents of relevant .pth files and editable modules in your venv, etc.

In any case, remember to run MkDocs with the verbose option to provide more accurate logs: `mkdocs serve -v`. This will help others helping you :)